# Java: Casting Enum<?>

Tags: java, generics, enums

Imagine I have this:

```
class MyClass<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private E myEnum;

    public MyClass(E myEnum) {
        this.myEnum = myEnum;
    }

    public E getMyEnum() { return myEnum; }
    public void setMyEnum(E e) { myEnum = e; }
}
```

Now I have these:

```
Enum<?> someRandomEnum = // Retrieved from somewhere

MyClass<?> enumClassA = new MyClass<>(someRandomEnum); // Cannot infer type arguments

MyClass<?> enumClassB = new MyClass<Object>(someRandomEnum); // Obviously Object is not subclass of an enum

MyClass<?> enumClassC = new MyClass<? extends Enum<?>>(someRandomEnum); // Cannot instantiate the type MyClass<? extends Enum<?>>
```

I have tried many ways to cast this, but I just can't fit an `Enum<?>` into a `MyClass<?>`. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: An instance of `MyClass<?>` cannot be an instance of `Enum<?>`, so casting it makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have to declare it as `MyClass<E extends Enum<E>>`? Can you just declare it `MyClass<E extends Enum<?>>`?

Comment: @khelwood I'm not really directly casting `Enum<?>` to `MyClass<?>`, `MyClass` stores a specific type of enum value, but for this one specific use-case, I want to loosen the type-safety because I know it won't throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried changing that `E` to `?` and I seem to cast fine. Is there any disadvantages or problems that can arise from changing this?

Comment: Casting between generics never throws - generic parameters are not preserved at runtime. You get the exceptions when you then access members that use the type parameter in an incompatible way.

Comment: I'm wondering what the use case is for this that isn't already covered by things like `EnumSet` and `EnumMap`.

Comment: Anyway, you can make it compile by leaving out the parameters for `MyClass` entirely. Of course, you'll have to suppress the resulting compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate a raw type, then cast:

```
MyClass<?> enumClassA = (MyClass<?>)new MyClass(someRandomEnum);
```

It compiles, but will generate the following (harmless) compiler warning:

> Unchecked call to 'MyClass(E)' as a member of raw type 'com.foo.bar.SomeRandomEnum'

which can be suppressed by adding this annotation

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

to the method containing this code.